# Parameter passing to function handle

Tags: matlab, function, parameter-passing, integral

I have a function and I want to each time change its input and integrate over a certain interval. For example, I first write an m file:

```
function y = myfun(x) 

y = 1 ./ (x.^3 - 2*x - 5);
```

Now I want to integrate functions like myfun(x-2) or myfun(2*x). Does anyone know how I should pass them? Integral(myfun(x-2),a,b) creates an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest calling `integral` on a handle for your function as below:

```
h1 = @(x)myfun(x);
h2 = @(x)myfun(x-2);
h3 = @(x)myfun(x.^2);

integral(h1,a,b);
integral(h2,a,b);
integral(h3,a,b);
```

This should trick the integral function into thinking that you are just defining `myfun` as a function of `x` while allowing you to pass whatever expression you want to it. You could also pass additional parameters this way, such as:

```
h = @(x)myfun(x, params);
integral(h,a,b);
```

Where `params` could be a list of parameters that you use in your definition of `myfun`.

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:** I tested this on a server that I have access to which does have the `integral` function and it seemed to work. Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: Yes it was exactly what I asked for :-)